# how should I initialize IQueryable variables, before use a Union expression?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I've created an extension method over IQueryable type, which takes a subset of entities and filters them upon some criterrions. My problem is that I can't return a Union expression made of the variables, without all being initialized first. Null values, as aprears, are not valid.

```
public static IQueryable<Person> FilterHairColors(this IQueryable<Person> subQuery, string[] hairColors)
    {
        IQueryable<Person> q1 = null;
        IQueryable<Person> q2 = null;
        IQueryable<Person> q3 = null;
        IQueryable<Person> q4 = null;

        foreach (var value in hairColors)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case "1":
                    q1 = subQuery.Where(p => p.HairColor_bright == true);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    q2 = subQuery.Where(p => p.HairColor_brown == true);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    q3 = subQuery.Where(p => p.HairColor_dark == true);
                    break;
                case "4":
                    q4 = subQuery.Where(p => p.HairColor_red == true);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return q1.AsQueryable().Union(q2.AsQueryable()).Union(q3.AsQueryable()).Union(q4.AsQueryable());
    }
```

The presented code block is part of several more, and each produces a subset of data, conveyed to a subsequent filtering method this way:

```
results = persons.FilterGender(vm.gender).FilterAge(vm.age).FilterHeight(vm.height)......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call Union when one of the arguments is null.

What does a "null-query" mean to you? If it means "no rows" then just don't Union it. If it means "all rows" you don't need to union because you can just take the underlying, unfiltered query.

Like this:

```
var result = new [] { q1, q2, q3, q4, }.Where(query => query != null).Aggregate(Queryable.Union);
```

This is using LINQ-to-Objects to construct a LINQ-to-SQL query.

A new version:

```
var result = dataContext.Persons.Where(_ => false);
if(q1 != null) result = result.Union(q1);
if(q2 != null) result = result.Union(q2);
if(q3 != null) result = result.Union(q3);
if(q4 != null) result = result.Union(q4);
```

The SQL Server query optimizer will remove the first dummy query so that it has no runtime cost at all.

Comment: Then how should I condition Union performing with non null variables?

Comment: Thanks 'usr'. Can you think of more simple, intuitive way to access my problem?

Comment: I added a new version. Not quite as sophisticated though ;-)

Comment: tnks. I will try that. Sorry for the novice questions but If I need to, how do I get ModelContext into the static class?

Comment: Glad to help. Not sure what you mean by ModelContext. I suggest you just ask a new question.

Comment: I managed - many thanks! What I ment is that since static class takes no constructor parameters, I see no convinient way to pass in a modelContext. (EF dataContext)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12647/discussion-between-tal-l-and-usr)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IQueryable<Person> FilterHairColors(this IQueryable<Person> subQuery, string[] hairColors)
{
    var result = new Person[] { }.AsQueryable();
    var contains = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Person, bool>>>();

    contains.Add("1", p => p.HairColor_bright);
    contains.Add("2", p => p.HairColor_brown);
    contains.Add("3", p => p.HairColor_dark);
    contains.Add("4", p => p.HairColor_red);

    foreach (var color in hairColors)
    {
        result = subQuery.Where(contains[color]).Union(result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, and it came with this error: "This method supports LINQ to Entity infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code". see topic regading: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/adodotnetentityframework/thread/3962b925-fe1e-4b96-ade3-5cb3b4be4511