# Union of a List of IQueryables

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

With:

```
var q1 = (IQueryable<T>).....;
var q2 = (IQueryable<T>).....;
var q3 = (IQueryable<T>).....;

var qList = new List<IQueryable<T>>{q1, q2, q3};
```

I want to do this:

```
var q = q1.Union(q2).Union(q3);
```

But using `qList` instead of using `q1`, `q2` and `q3`. I tried with `qList.SelectMany` but the behavior is different (the queryables are queries to a database and `SelectMany` makes a query for each queryable instead of just one query).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067226/how-should-i-initialize-iqueryable-variables-before-use-a-union-expression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) extension method:

```
var q = qList.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Union(y));
```

Or following Thomas Levesque's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437067/union-of-a-list-of-iqueryables#comment28818318_19437117):

```
var q = qList.Aggregate(Queryable.Union);
```

This will pick the first item from `qList`, union it with the second item, union the result with the third item, and so on for each item in `qList`. Note that this would not actually involve evaluating any of the `IQueryable<T>`'s, just constructing a new `IQueryable<T>` which represents a union of the others.

Comment: You could also write it like this: `qList.Aggregate(Queryable.Union)`